# How to translate this statement with quantifiers?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

"If one person gets a project extension then everyone gets a project extension"

E(x) denotes x gets a project extension

Is this correct?

$∃ x E(x) \rightarrow ∀ x E(x)$

Or do I also have denote "person/people"?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the universe of discourse is defined.  If that is defined to be 'persons', then what you have is correct. But if it is 'objects on planet Earth', then you will need to introduce a person predicate.